# Is there any way to convert 50 Hz directly to 1 MHz?

Tags: ac, converter, high-frequency

I want to know whether there are any ways to convert 50 Hz AC to 1 MHz without Voltage Controlled Oscillators?

If I'm correct, all the normal circuits convert the AC to DC and then use it to oscillate a high frequency oscillator. I want to know whether the frequency gain can be achieved without the conversion?

If not, which is the best possible way using VCO idea?

Comment: Use a crystal? What voltage/current input and output (pk-pk)? You want 120/220/240 V @ 1 MHz?

Comment: @Greenonline Conversation should be from 230V/50Hz to 230V/1MHz. I was asking for a direct ac-ac conversion technique. I think crystal oscillator technique is used in ac-dc-ac conversion.

Comment: How much power do you need from the output? What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: No, there is no way of "direct" conversion. And if using VCO, PLLs are used to multiply frequencies.

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm not good at electronics for the start. If anything is wrong in what I say pls feel free to correct it. And as far as the problem is I don't wanna concentrate on the power. My focus is only on frequency gain.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So you are saying that ax-ac direct converters cannot be used here?

Comment: What is ac-ac direct converter? A transformer? These are not changing frequency.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem It seems highly likely that you do not actually need 230V/1MHz

Comment: @BeB00 See I need to convert 230v/50Hz to 230v/1MHz. That's my goal. Nothing else.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Most papers are only talking about the power conversation. My question is that, Is it possible to do the same for Frequency part using some switching systems (like cycloconverters) ?

Comment: I guess it really depends on which components you are ruling out, and at what point "direct" becomes "indirect".

Comment: What do you need 230V/1MHz for?

Comment: *My focus is only on frequency gain* It is possible to amplify a **signal** and that means the voltage (and/or current) swing is increased. We **cannot** "amplify" the frequency, frequency is **events per time** and changing events means creating new ones (which might not be the same) or changing time (no idea how to do that). So applying a "gain" to a frequency isn't possible. Sure we can **multiply** a frequency (using a PLL) but that increases the number of events.

Comment: So, do you want a black box which takes in 50 Hz 230 VAC (+/- some number of percent on both) and get out 1 MHz 230 VAC (with both frequency and voltage able to drift a bit)? Or do you want 1 MHz to track changes in the 50 Hz?

Comment: VTC unclear. As long as you won't tell us what this is for, the question is nonsensical and most answers will likely end up getting a "no that's not what I mean" comment.

Comment: @pipe This is a college project topic given by the faculty. I don't know the application of it. He told me that he'll tell me, after I get it done.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Circuitry for the black box which takes in 230V/50Hz AC and gives 230V/1MHz AC

Comment: This is unanswerable until you specify what *aspect* of the 50 Hz you wish to convert.  Power?  Information?  Of what sort?  Either whoever assigned this problem to you provided information which you have failed to pass on, or they have no idea what they are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of a meaningless question unless you tell us what you are really trying to do - are you trying to move power around? just taking part in an intellectual exercise? ??

There's lots of ways - I suggest you turn the 50hz into nice square waves by amplifying and clipping, then build a filter and amplifier to pick out the 1,000,000/50 = 20,000th harmonic from the hash (or maybe more practically a cascading series of filters and amplifiers to pick out continually increasing harmonics)

Answer (score 4):

If you want 1MHz pulsating at 50Hz you can use a [spark gap transmitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark-gap_transmitter) circuit from days of old.

[image]

You step the voltage up to some thousands of volts using a 50Hz transformer, then the spark gap excites an L-C resonant circuit. You would then need an air-core transformer to get back down to 230V or so.

They commonly operated at frequencies around 1MHz (300m wavelength). 
[image]

This is not a good way, not at all, but it involves no active components.

Comment: Wow! Obscure knowledge! Does the 50hz Hv A.c. go where the battery is?

Comment: @KH Yes, the output of the high-voltage transformer (that wooden box in the photo).

Comment: I was thinking of some swing analogy, where you just push some resonant apparatus. So apparently this is the one. It's just that it is not converting 50Hz as far as I understand, but like any frequency.

Comment: when i saw the question on the list, my immediate reaction was *"yeah, with this thing we call a '**radio transmitter**'."*

Comment: That, or an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexanderson_alternator and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldschmidt_alternator for lower frequencies. Sometimes used on ships. Didn't help the Titanic.